# What is the probability of $P(X \leq 2$ or $Y \leq 2$)?

Tags: probability

**Edit:** Updated it to accurately represent the problem given.

Two stochastic variables $X$ and $Y$ both with with $S_x = S_y = \{1,2,3,4\}$
$P(X=j) = 1/4 $ for $j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$
$$P(Y=j) = \begin{cases}   
1/8 & \text{if $j = 1$}\\   
1/4 & \text{if $j = 2$}\\   
3/8 & \text{if $j = 3$}\\ 
1/4 & \text{if $j = 4$}
\end{cases}
$$
$X$ and $Y$ are independent.
What is the probability of $P(X \leq 2$ or $Y \leq 2$)?

Comment: Actually, i was mistaken, i have edited the question. Seems like it is mutually exclusive after all.

Comment: Hint for the latest (and I hope last) version of the question. Model this by tossing two four sided dice, one fair, the other unfair as specified.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit the question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hint: try to compute the probability of the complementary event, i.e., $$\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq 3 \text{ and } Y \geq 3\}$$and use independence for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X\le2)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(Y\le2)=\frac{3}{8}$.

Using the result $P(A \text  { or } B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, the answer is therefore $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}-\frac{3}{16}=\frac{11}{16}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Surely the chance of x being 2, 3 or 4 is 3/4th?

Comment: Does this elaboration help?

Comment: Not really, since i dont know why you set the probability of P(X<=2) to 1/2, since it should be 3/4

Comment: A quarter plus a quarter?

Comment: You are working out P(X>=2) not P(X<=2) @Drax

Comment: Holy s***, ive somehow gotten it switched around in my head, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try to compute the probability of the complementary event, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq 3 \text{ and } Y \geq 3\}
$$
and use independence for that.

**Details:** *(place your mouse over the hidden text to reveal it)*

> We have $$ \mathbb{P}\{ X \leq 2 \text{ or } Y \leq  2\} = 1-\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq 3 \text{ and } Y \geq 3\} = 1-\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq 3 \}\mathbb{P}\{ Y \geq 3\} = 1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{8} = \frac{11}{16} $$ using independence of $X$ and $Y$ to obtain the second equality.